# Installed Nvidia driver from website and now Ubuntu won't even start up

Tags: nvidia, screen

Installed Nvidia driver from website and now Ubuntu won't even start up. Just a black screen with a flashing cursor. I did a boot-repair but did nothing? Very frustrating. Any solutions or is it still a problem?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to install nvidea drivers if u install the linux-headers for u kernel and do `sudo nvidea-xconfig` after u installed the drivers. Or u can install a ppa that provide better support https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

When you see the black screen did you try and type "CTRL+ALT+F1" to see if you can acces the terminal?
If you can, then you should remove the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Nouveau can be blacklisted sometimes, so let's be sure it is not:

```
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Last , search for the xorg.conf file and remove it as well.

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: I am having major troubles. I remember running into Ctrl Alt F1 when I ran the nvidia.run file. I then rebooted and when I choose Ubuntu to boot it shows the terminal for 2 seconds then goes blank so I cannot access anything. I then restart and go into recovery mode then "drop to root shell prompt" removed nvidia drivers. But don't know what to do from here?

Comment: Oh it works now. so confused lol. I repaired the packages then ran and it now works.

Comment: Ok first of all, don't panic. Now where you have tried to unninstall nvidia drivers, witch you say you did unninstall them, just run the commands i wrote.

Comment: @Rat2000 the proper way is to add a answer as this is not a "post" this is a question and answer site.